# Allow authors to only post on admin-approved pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-controls

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question but I've been thrust into running full stack (website as well as iOS and Android apps) for a company after they previously contracted work to some sloppy programmers.  Documentation is sparse and the code base is a mess.

They're running the site off of WordPress.  A feature of the site/apps is to allow certain users (the authors) to post updates.

Each author has a page of their own.  When a post goes up, it goes live on the aggregated feed as well as their own unique author page.

Currently authors can post, however the issue is that they can post to any page.  Whats worse is they have access to other features of the site (such as creating new pages, etc.)

How can I properly police these author permissions?  Is there a different type of user group more suitable to what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [wordpress.se]

Comment: @brasofilo You're probably right. I will ask my question over at that site. Can an admin close or delete this for me in that case? Thanks.

Comment: Research ***before asking***, please. Here or there.

Comment: @brasofilo I researched here before posting and found no similar issues to my dilemma. As WordPress tags exist here, I assumed the post was relevant to the community.  I am new to StackExchange and was unaware of a WordPress sub-community. From now on I will divert any WordPress related questions, _after researching_, to that community.  Apologies.

Comment: No problem, it's just the nature of the Stack sites. One is supposed to show research efforts when asking. And I'm pretty sure you'll find material to go further (or even solving) before asking. Good luck!